# Inheritance Tree for Task Types in Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, build, gradle

How do I cleanly separate tasks that might require two different configuration tasks in Gradle?  I'm attempting to separate the actual tasks that I want to execute in a buildSrc/dbhelpertasks.gradle file from the parent build.gradle file.  build.gradle will contain partially configured tasks that are used in dbhelpertasks.gradle.

I have a number of different databases that I want to connect and execute SQL on so I created a SQLServerTask that takes a database name and URL.

Custom SQLServerTask.groovy

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
import groovy.sql.Sql


class SQLServerTask extends DefaultTask {
    def hostname
    def database
    def port = 1433
    def username
    def password
    def sql
    def sqlServerDriver = 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'

    @TaskAction
    def executeSql() {
        url = hostname + ":" + port + "/" + database
        databaseConnProps = [user: username, password: password]
        def sqlInstance = Sql.newInstance(url, databaseConnProps, sqlServerDriver)
        println "I would execute " + sql
    }

}
```

I then created a task in my build.gradle that would configure the SQLServerTask with some of the properties.

build.gradle

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
apply from: 'buildSrc/dbhelpertasks.gradle'
repositories { 
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    driver
}

dependencies {
    driver group: 'net.sourceforge.jtds', name: "jtds", version: "1.2.4"
}

//Load up all the drivers for use in this project
URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
configurations.driver.each {File file ->
    loader.addURL(file.toURL())
}

task contentDbTask(type: SQLServerTask) {
    println "Configuring content db task"
    hostname = contentDbUrl
    database = contentDbName
    username = contentDbUserName
    password = contentDbPassword
}
```

The dbhelpertasks.gradle file contains the final configuration (SQL Statement) of the actual tasks that I want to execute.

buildSrc/dbhelpertasks.gradle

```
task getSiteParams(type: contentDbTask) {
    println "Configuring Site Params Task"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM CMS_SITE_PARAM"
}
```

When I execute `gradle getSiteParams` it ends up failing

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find property 'contentDbTask' on root project 'shipyard'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of misconceptions here.

First, only class `SQLServerTask` should be in `buildSrc`, as the only purpose of `buildSrc` is to produce classes which are then used by the main build.

`dbhelpertasks.grovvy` would typically go into a top-level `gradle` directory (sibling of `buildSrc`) and end in `.gradle`. Preconfiguration of a task, like `contentDbTask` does, would typically be done by a plugin (like the `dbhelpertasks.gradle` script plugin) rather than a task.

A task's type is always a class, so `task getSiteParams(type: contentDbTask)` won't work. Also, `dbhelpertasks.groovy` can't see tasks added (or any other configuraion done) by `build.gradle`, only the other way around. This is because the latter applies the former at the very top (which is fine).

Comment: Thank you Peter.  I had a mistake in the dbhelpertasks.gradle name.  It was indeed .gradle not .groovy.  I followed your suggestion and moved this into the gradle directory (sibling of buildSrc).

I'll follow your suggestion and have preconfiguration of a task done by a plugin and change getSiteParams to have the type of that plugin.  Would the plugin be in dbhelpertasks.gradle and would it have access to gradle.properties ?

Comment: `dbhelpertasks.gradle` *is* a (script) plugin. You don't have to turn it into a binary plugin (i.e. implementation of the `Plugin` interface). `gradle.properties` isn't accessed directly; instead, all properties in `gradle.properties` automatically become properties of the `project` object. Therefore, `dbhelpertasks.gradle` will have access to all of them.

Comment: Ok so i'll create a plugin that willpreconfigure the contentDbTask. I guess where i am lost is how to re-use that preconfigured task with the final custom configuration. I can create the preconfigured tasks no problem in the plugin, i'm just wondering how the heck to finalize a configuration and reuse the task multiple times with my custom sql stuff.  For example, once i have a ContentDbTask with the preconfigured connection information, i would like to execute that task with different SQL statements in the DAG.

Comment: `dbhelpertasks.gradle` can preconfigure all `ContentDbTask` tasks with `tasks.withType(ContentDbTask) { ... }`. This configuration will get applied to all tasks of that type, no matter who creates them. By the way, the task type shouldn't have `Task` in its name.

Comment: TIGHT! I will try this out.    Is there a style guide I can checkout that points out the Task naming convention?

Comment: Oh i'm missing something.  if the plugin preconfigures ContentDbTask tasks, how do i create the ContentDbTask type that extends SQLServerTask?  I assume in another ContentDBTask.groovy file right?

Comment: Not sure why you need another task type, but if you do, you'd typically put it into `buildSrc/ContentDBTask.groovy`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18195/discussion-between-shaun-f-and-peter-niederwieser)